# Why isn't this query working properly?

Tags: php, sql

Basically am trying to make an attandance system

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE role='H' OR role='F' AND department='CIVIL'";
```

here is H mean Head of dep.
and F means Faculty

Now when i run this query this also fetch the result which have department with CSE now i only want CIVIL dep.

How can i resolve this??

Comment: I think you are just missing parentheses: `where (role = 'H' or role = 'F')`.  Or better yet, `where role in ('H','F')`

Comment: use braces in the query ie `( ( role='H' or role='F') and department='civil' )`

Comment: Your real problem is you marked this PHP when their isn't any PHP code in it.

Answer (score 10):

Use parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE (role='H' OR role='F')
AND department='CIVIL'
```

because `AND` has a stronger binding (precedence) than `OR`.

Without parentheses your query would be like this

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE role='H' 
OR (role='F' AND department='CIVIL')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your query has a boolean logic problem.  It does *work*, it just doesn't do what you want.

The simplest solution is to use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE role IN ('H', 'F') AND department = 'CIVIL';
```

The advice for the future is that if you have `AND` and `OR` in the same `WHERE`, then use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE role='H' OR role='F' AND department='CIVIL'
```

Your Query returned CSE dept in output because you not used parentheses in the required place. So this query will return all rows where role='H' or 
role='F' and department='CIVIL'

simply  parenthesis addition in your query like below way will work properly

```
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE (role='H' OR role='F')
 AND department='CIVIL'
```